# Difference in preprocessor output

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I was trying to check some single line macros which have 2 pre-processor directives.

```
#define REPLACE  { \
#if EXT == 42 \
#warning "Got 42" \
#endif \
}

int main(void){
    REPLACE;
    return 0;
}
```

The pre-processor parses this fine yielding:

```
$g++ -E includetest.cpp
# 1 "includetest.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "includetest.cpp"

int main(void){
    { #if EXT == 42 #warning "Got 42" #endif };
    return 0;
}
```

which of course is illegal code, since just macro substitution occurs and the ifdef lookalike macro isn't processed again even though it looks like one.

Now if I slightly alter the macro to look something like

```
#define REPLACE(a)  { a + 2 ; \
#if EXT == 42 \
#warning "Got 42" \
#endif \
}

int main(void){
    REPLACE(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Which yields this pre-processor error:

```
$g++ -E includetest.cpp
# 1 "includetest.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "includetest.cpp"
includetest.cpp:1:18: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
 #define REPLACE(a)  { a + 2 ; \
                  ^
int main(void){
    REPLACE(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this error come up ? Of course, this won't compile but I want to know why addition of a parameter ensues in a parsing error from pre-processor ?

People would say " You can't nest another directive in another", but in the first case too they are nested, why doesn't pre-processor error out then ? Or is that responsibility delegated to the compiler ?

EDIT: I am not trying to achieve any functionality per se, this is just an exercise (in futility?) to understand the pre-processor.

Comment: you are expecting things from the preprocessor that it simply cannot do. It does not recursively substitute, its only one pass. And BTW 99% of what you want to do is doable with pure c++, complex macros are never needed for c++

Comment: As a macro cannot be used to define another macro, why do you care?

Comment: @pm100 I think you haven't understood my question . I am asking why is there a difference in output. I don't want it to "do things', I'm just asking why it behaves thus ?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ok. Could you please direct me to the standard or reference where it mentions that ? I couldn't find it. Also this isn't another 'macro in a macro', right ? It's just another directive in the same line.

Comment: The first one is an object-like macro, the second one is a function-like macro.  The macro function will act on the macro function parameter, which is what `#if` tries to do, but `if` is not a macro parameter, so fails.

Comment: @Eljay When you see `if` isn't a macro parameter, you mean the `#if` is acting as the stringize operator and thus looking for `#a`?

Comment: Correct, the token `#` is an operator in the context of a macro function's body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only inside a function macro does a `#` have special meaning ([[cpp.stringize]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.stringize#1)). The standard says that a `#` needs to be followed by a function argument, which is not happening in your second case (`if`, `warning` and `endif` are not parameters).

Your first case is valid (you can actually have directives inside the replacement list of object macros) exactly because there `#` doesn't have any special meaning.